# How to use mapbox mapping with nuxt.js and vue leaflet?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js, mapbox, vue2leaflet

Trying to add mapping to my nuxt.js app, no luck so far.
there is this package nuxt-leaflet, but it has very little activity, and only the very basic example.
I would love to use mapbox layers, and build the map dynamically with the leaflet L object. any basic example, tutorial, link, would be great.

Comment: how is your implementation in your `nuxtjs`? i am using `vue2leaflet` with Nuxt and it is working fine

Comment: thanks @kusiaga, I'll give it a try. nuxt-leaflet is a wrapper around vue2leaflet, but if it doesn't work then lets go to the source. thanks!